# Connecting a webpage to an OCR engine

Tags: java, web-applications, web, ocr

I am working on a website that at one point will ask for a user’s first name, last name, a photo ID, and an email address.
Now I need to validate that the photo ID has actually the same name as the first and last name entered, which means some OCR or image processing needs to happen. 
I do not want this to be done via an external API cos I have to guarantee to users that the photo will remain within be site and not exposed to other third parties. 
I don’t really know best way to do this, I was thinking maybe some java application?? 
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The big challenge here is to make sure your solution can handle even moderate levels of traffic.

There are plenty of OCR engines you can invoke via an API. Tesseract has [dozens of wrappers](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/AddOns#tesseract-wrappers), complete with documentation. The obvious solution would be (pseudo code):

```
show data input form with file upload.
store uploaded file to disk.
invoke OCR API with uploaded file, get back strings.
pattern match (regex or similar) for name.
```

However, this solution would likely create a scalability problem/denial of service option. The OCR library would run synchronously with the web request, and consume that server thread while it runs; the OCR application is likely to be (fairly) slow, and an attacker could really slow it down by uploading an image that's very hard to convert. That would mean just a few (comparatively) requests could bring down your web server.

Much better to put the scanning task on an asynchronous queue, and have an application that doesn't run in the context of your web request handle it, and then pass back the validation status.

In pseudo code (web application)

```
show data input form with file upload.
create database record for user.
store uploaded file to disk.
put task on the job queue
use client-side JavaScript to wait for update of database status (Ajax/React)
when status changes, show update to user
```

The application listening to the job queue:

```
see new job.
use disk file to start OCR process
scan for name (Regex) in results
update database record for this user
```

Most web application frameworks support queues; if you're working in Java you could use [JQM](https://jqm.readthedocs.io/en/jqm-all-2.0.0/), and Spring supports this sorta kinda [out of the box.](http://yysource.com/2016/05/spring-boot-executing-asynchronous-method-backed-with-a-queue/)

Comment: I think tesserect would be the best solution for this scenario, thank you for the asynchronous idea, I can just show a revolving icon and tell users not to close the page.